# How to change invoice status paid to pending_payment when order status is processing

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

I have used Magento version 1.9, when order is placed then order status is pending. when submit invoice then order status changes to processing but invoice status is showing paid.

But I want to change invoice status paid to pending_payment while order status processing and when ship order then invoice status change to paid.

How to do that?

Comment: My `invoice[capture_case]` was missing in invoice create form. I have added `invoice[capture_case]` in invoice form. Now there is no problem with creating invoice.

Comment: Processing status means that the payment method has been captured. If you want your status to be pending, you should ensure that your payment method doesn't get captured/charged in the processing of creating your invoice. This is likely to be a configuration issue, and you should **not** hack up the Magento orders/payments framework to undo business logic like this - you will regret it later on.

Answer (score -1):

## Solution 1

**Working with an existing invoice**

To change an existing invoice status from `paid` to `pending` is actually quite simple despite all the complexity built around it.

To do this, pay no attention to the invoice `status` but focus solely on the invoice `state`. All you have to do is change the invoice `state` to the new desired state and the `status` gets updated as well.

Since the invoice has already been paid for, you probably want to reset the `total_paid` and `base_total_paid` fields of the particular order the invoice was for so you at some point later on mark it as paid.

This should do just that:

```
<?php

    $incrementId = '100014637';
    $invoiceModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice');
    try {
        $invoice = $invoiceModel->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load((int)$invoice->getOrderId());
        $order->setTotalPaid(0)
                ->setBaseTotalPaid(0)
                ->save();

        $invoice->setState(1)
                ->save();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        var_dump($ex->getMessage()); die;
    }
```

To later mark it as paid on shipping, all you need do is simply get the invoice and call the `pay` method on it.

## Solution 2

**Working with a new invoice**

In order to create a `pending` invoice, the payment method you use for the order must allow you to do such.
For that you need to override the payment method model and add these membere:

```
protected $_canCapture = true; // sets state to open
protected $_canCapturePartial = true; // lets you invoice partially
```

For example if you want to do this for Check/money order or Cash On Delivery you need to override either app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Checkmo.php or app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Cashondelivery.php and add the above attribute.

After this when you create an invoice you will have an option near the save button to set the invoice status. To create a pending invoice select `Not capture` as seen below.

[image]

If you want to mark it later as paid edit the invoice and between the buttons on to one called `Capture`.

[image]

Since what you want to do is mark it as paid on shipping, all you need do is simply get the invoice and call the `pay` method on it.

Hope it helps someone.